# Calculate the net force of water on the cylinder. (See picture)

Tags: fluid-statics

I was working on this question, which wants me to find the net force on the cylinder due to the water. (It is 5 meters long) that is plugging a hole in a tank.I know to find the net downwards force I do the typical weight of water in the purple area.

My problem arises when I try to find the upwards force due to the water in the orange area. What would I do? Subtract the water weight in the orange area? or calculate the buoyant force on the red areas of the cylinder?[image: Question Setup]

Comment: You might want to read up on Archimedes' principle (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes'_principle )

Comment: @Bort the standard calculation of buoyancy assumed the body totally surrounded by the liquid. In this case the bottom is apparently not, what I am not sure from the description is that if it is on the open air (so $p=p_{atm}$) or if touching some bottom of the container without water, it will be the normal force

Comment: @brucesmitherson below the hole it is plugging is air and above the water is air

Comment: @brucesmitherson ah okay, tbh I did not give too much attention to the picture. Then you would have to integrate over the surface to compute the total force (you know the pressure, either hydrostatic or airpressure)

Comment: i actually just figured it out using the second method of buoyancy of the red areas.